# How would I build a linux based router?

Tags: linux, router, kerberos, clearos

I am looking into building a Linux based router out of a home-built Linux server. I don't have much experience with the software required however.
I would like the server to run the following applications

```
router
firewall
kerberos auth server
```

Optionally, I would like to compliment with an email server.

Can you suggest a good combination of software to fulfill my needs? I would prefer that the router and firewall be web configurable.

As a bonus question. I tripped over [ClearOS](http://www.clearfoundation.com/Software/overview.html) while googling my way thorough the problem. But I haven't been able to figure out if it is a closed web-configurable router or if it is a fully fledged OS underneath. Does anyone know if you can get access to a terminal and install extra packages on it? I would have to have a need to install some extra component and be unable to because I installed a closed system.

Comment: If there is any plan to setup in Separate PC, Use pfsense PC need with 2 Ethernet Port, And its rock solid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arch Linux Wiki has a really good guide on how to do it with IPTables.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Router

Answer (score 1):

Well regarding router, you can easily configure one in a linux box using the **ip route** command.

To display routes in your system:

```
ip route show
```

To add a default route

```
ip route add default via IP-OF-GATEWAY
```

To add a new network

```
ip route add YOUR-NETWORK-RANGE via GATEWAY-FOR-NETWORK
```

Then firewall you have Netfilter/Iptables, which is a huge topic, you can ask specific questions on your requirements and get answers.